# Rshiny publish error: inferAppPrimaryDoc Execution halted

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyjs

I created an Rshiny APP on my Mac and tried to upload to shinyapps.io

However, when I press 'Publish' button at the top right corner, it shows an error.

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 609021...Error in inferAppPrimaryDoc(appPrimaryDoc = appPrimaryDoc, appFiles = appFiles,  : 
  Application mode static requires at least one document.
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withStatus -> force -> bundleApp -> inferAppPrimaryDoc
Execution halted
```

This problem has been solved. See the first answer.

But now, I have another problem.

I can publish it, but the app cannot show the graphs.

I check the log and it says,

```
Warning: Error in : Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, label, vjust, fill
```

Also, there is another warning,

```
Warning in Ops.factor(Year, start) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors.
```

It is pretty strange because when I run the app on my own laptop, it works super well. Please help...

Thanks,

Weichen

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to split your code to ui.R and server.R. 
Here is how I solved it on Rstudio:

I created a new Shiny app.R file.

This creates a new folder inside the working directory. I copied all data files I use inside my app into that folder.

I copied and pasted my whole code into the new app.R file on Rstudio.

I clicked Publish and I chose all the data files I use together with the app.R for upload.

It worked. I am not sure why it wasn't working before even though I was still choosing the right files together; I guess because they weren't in the right folder for the Shiny app.

edit: don't forget to Save the app.R file before publishing

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

At first, I simply execute the shiny.R (the whole code) Wrong!

Try this. Create two r files under the same directory.

ui.R

server.R

and then executive shiny.R

You would see an amazing thing happen.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the second problem.

Change the type of 'Year' to numeric by `as.numeric`

However, I still cannot understand because I can run app on my own laptop.

BTW, the logs in shinyapps.io help me target the problem.